# OpenGL ES 2.0 Invalid operation on framebuffer creation

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to render to a texture, and then draw a texture into a square. While creating the framebuffer, I get Invalid operation after `glFramebufferRenderbuffer` and `glFramebufferTexture2D` calls. Here is the function that should create the framebuffer:

```
private void createFrameBuffer()
{
    final int[] texture = new int[1];
    frameTextureID = texture[0];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1,texture,0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameTextureID);

    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

    final int[] depthBuffer = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenRenderbuffers(1, depthBuffer, 0);
    renderBufferID = depthBuffer[0];

    GLES20.glBindRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer[0]);
    GLES20.glRenderbufferStorage(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);

    final int[] frameBuffer = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1,frameBuffer,0);
    frameBufferID = frameBuffer[0];
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER,frameBufferID);

    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, frameTextureID, 0);
    error("glFramebufferTexture2D");
    GLES20.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT  , GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBufferID);
    error("glFramebufferRenderbuffer");

    frameBufferComplete("createFrameBuffer");

    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

I don't understand what's wrong with that.

ps: The framebuffer is complete when I check at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These first few statements are in the wrong order:

```
final int[] texture = new int[1];
frameTextureID = texture[0];
GLES20.glGenTextures(1,texture,0);
```

You get the value of `texture[0]` before it is set by `glGenTextures()`. So `frameTextureID` will always be 0.

Instead, this should be:

```
final int[] texture = new int[1];
GLES20.glGenTextures(1,texture,0);
frameTextureID = texture[0];
```

Also note that RGBA8 (RGBA with 8-bit components) is not guaranteed to be a renderable format in ES 2.0. This is what you're using for your texture with the combination of `GL_RGBA` and `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`. Many implementations support it with the [OES_rgb8_rgba8 extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_rgb8_rgba8.txt). But if you want to be completely sure tat your code works on all devices, you need to use one of the supported formats, like RGB565:

```
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0,
                    GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, null);
```